# Deleting elements from linked lists in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

So I know the background of what I have to do. Link previous element to the next. But whatever I try I get segmentation faults (LINUX GCC). So can somebody see what I'm doing wrong. The print function is working fine so the fault has to be somewhere in the function. Code following...

DEFINITION... (EDIT)
Im sorry, posting declarations now...

```
    typedef struct Word {
        char *word;
        int count;
        struct Word *next;
    } Word;

    typedef Word* Dictionary;

void delete_word (Dictionary dict, char* str){
    Dictionary tempprev=dict;
    dict=dict->next;
    Dictionary tempnext=dict->next;
    while (dict!=NULL){
        if (strcmp(dict->word,str)==0){
            tempprev->next=tempnext;
            free (dict->word);
        }
        tempprev=dict;
        dict=dict->next;
        tempnext=dict->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use pen and paper to draw the pointers.

Comment: @Đugum Roko Show at least how the name Dictionary is defined.

Comment: It really is worth drawing out a diagram with some boxes and arrows. Also, as a general preference, I find that hiding pointers behind a typedef _always_ makes things confusing later. Especially when you probably need a pointer-to-pointer, in case you remove the head ...

Comment: regarding: `dict=dict->next;
    ....
    while (dict!=NULL){` if the linked list contains 0 entries, then this is accessing just above memory address 0..   The result will be a seg fault event

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show how the name Dictionary is defined. Taking into account the provided function it seems the name `Dictionary` is a typedef name that denotes a pointer.

If so then the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void delete_word( Dictionary *dict, const char *word )
{
    while ( *dict )
    {
        if ( strcmp( ( *dict )->word, word ) == 0 )
        {
            Dictionary current = *dict;
            *dict = ( *dict )->next;
            free( current );
        }
        else
        {
            dict = &( *dict )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

And if in main you a have a pointer having the type `Dictionary` like

```
Dictionary dict;
```

then the function is called like

```
delete_word( &dict, word );
```

If the list can contain only one node with a given word then the function definition can look the following way

```
void delete_word( Dictionary *dict, const char *word )
{
    while ( *dict && strcmp( ( *dict )->word, word ) != 0 )
    {
        dict = &( *dict )->next;
    }

    if ( *dict )
    {
        Dictionary current = *dict;
        *dict = ( *dict )->next;
        free( current );
    }
}
```

Comment: @ĐugumRoko This data member int count; does not make a sense. In any case I showed how the function can be defined.

Comment: It counts word repeating showing, not related to this function.